# Payment gateway that doesn't require site to be PCI compliant

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net, pci-compliance

I have been looking at authorize.net, notably their CIM and DPM solutions.  The problem is that I can't just reference a CIM profile in the DPM.  For people who don't use authorize.net, basically authorize.net manages my user's stored credit cards (on their site), but I can't use the ID of their stored credit card to make a payment through DPM, I have to retrieve that information from their servers, and pass it back to them in another request.  This act forces me to be PCI compliant (because I've handled the credit card numbers).

My question is: is there another provider that would allow me to use something similar to authorize.net but that allows my site to never touch the credit card/shipping information?

Comment: My understanding is that at least level 4 self certification is required regardless of which payment provider you use or if your site touches card/shipping data or not.

Comment: This is the first site I've dealt with the pci-compliance, so that might be true.  Though I would be surprised.  Considering sites that use paypal buy button would then technically to need pci-compliance

Comment: Trouble is there seems to be nowhere you can get a straight answer. Payment providers have PCI compliance partners that just wanna rip you off as much as possible and will tell you anything to get a sale... All this PCI DSS stuff is getting my back up at the moment :-)

Comment: Same, I have been looking at a ton of information, and I'm still in early beta of the site (designing the shopping cart).  It's getting annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're required by your merchant bank to be PCI compliant no matter what, but the requirements  can be reduced if you use other services that handle the transfer of credit card data to your gateway.

If credit card data touches your servers, you likely need to fill out Self-Assessment Questionnaire C: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_saq_c_v2.doc

If you use a service that handles this transfer, you'll likely only need Self Assessment Questionnaire A (but be sure to check with any service you're looking at): https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_saq_a_v2.doc

Disclaimer: I work for Recurly, one of the services you can use to minimize the scope of your PCI compliance. You may also want to take a look at Chargify, ChedderGetter, or SaaSy, but I'm happy to answer any of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Infintech](http://infintechllc.com/index.html) allows that, although it's not crystal clear from their web site. On your site, you need a way to identify the user, but you don't need to store credit card information, addresses, or anything like that.